MacOS + Sail (Docker) + Vite = Browser can't connect over port 5173
The Problem
Vite appears to be running, according shell in Terminal, but does not update the page, recognize CSS changes and is not accessible over port 5173 on localhost.
Context

I am on macOS Sonoma 14.5
Running Laravel 11
Running Laravel Sail
Running npm run dev to utilize Vite
Application runs fine without site on http://localhost, even when Vite is running, but does not update.
Output for Vite in Terminal indicates it's running and watching files.
Output for Vite in Safari Console indicates the page cannot access 5173

Shell Output in Terminal
  VITE v5.3.1  ready in 106 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/
  ➜  Network: http://172.20.0.3:5173/
  ➜  press h + enter to show help

  LARAVEL v11.10.0  plugin v1.0.4

  ➜  APP_URL: http://localhost

Console Output
[Error] Failed to load resource: Could not connect to the server. (client, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: Could not connect to the server. (app.css, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: Could not connect to the server. (header.js, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: Could not connect to the server. (app.js, line 0)
[Log] Users Data: – [] (0) (localhost, line 164)


If Vite is running in Docker, have you bound a host port to container port 5173?

Also, I don't understand "does not update the page, recognize CSS changes and is not accessible over port 5173". How can you know it's not updating or recognising CSS changes if you can't even open it?

I resolved the issue. The cause was I referenced port 5174 in Docker.yml line 13: - '${VITE_PORT:-5174}:${VITE_PORT:-5173}' but I did not add that reference to .env VITE_PORT=5174.
Once I added that, and re-built, re-up'd it worked.
